# How can I determine the type of C# file in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When you try to create a new C# file in Visual Studio, one has plenty of options. And most of the different file types, like Windows Form, Custom Control, C# Class file, Installer Class, etc. have have an extension .cs. I know that in the base they are all just C# files, and Visual Studio just includes some code snippets for our chosen file type. But, is it possible to somehow check what kind of file type has been used in Visual Studio, when created that particular source file?

For example, I have a file in a solution called `FileDialogPane.cs`, and inside I have something like this:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;

namespace Project.File
{
    internal class FileDialogPage : DialogPage
    {
        public FileDialogPage()
        {
            InitializeSettings();
        }

        // rest removed for brevity
    }
}
```

And it doesn't have a default .cs style logo in Visual Studio, and I really want to figure out what kind of file was used when creating it.

Comment: Designer files and codebehind files can both have a CS extension but they are quite different as designer files are auto-generated and could have changes wiped out if one is familiar with this structure in some Web project types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I'm afraid not -- not generally. Once created, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, checking inheritance works. You can see this file inherits the class `DialogPage`, which makes this a [DialogPage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.dialogpage.aspx) file.

Comment: I thought about it. But, for example, when you do Add an Item in C#, as long as I know there isn't any DialogPane file type. It is just a class that it inherits from, or am I wrong?